# How can I remove the dollar sign from a javascript variable wrapped in percentage signs?

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm looking at a shopping cart that echos a variable when it is wrapped with two percentage signs.

For example, on an html page %%Amount%% would echo something like $4.50.

In javascript, I have something that reads:

```
var tag_params = {
prodid: '',
pagetype: 'cart',
totalvalue: '%%Amount%%',
};
```

The output for totalvalue contains a dollar sign, and I need to remove it.

How can I do this with the example above?

**UPDATE:**

I think that Ian and abc123 most likely gave the correct answer to this.  In my particular case, it was not providing the output that I wanted to see in the source code, so I created a new global variable and removed the dollar sign in php then and there.

This echoed it the way I wanted when using %%ModifiedAmount%%.

Comment: `tag_params.totalvalue = tag_params.totalvalue.replace(/^\$/, "");`. Or I'm sure it would be easier to do `tag_params.totalvalue = tag_params.totalvalue.slice(1);` if you know for sure it will **always** start with a "$"

Comment: How/where does this conversion from `%%Amount%%` to `$4.50` take place? Because obviously you need the `replace` to take place *after* that.

Comment: Why is it echoing the dollar sign if you don't want it?

Comment: Note that your trailing `,` will cause an error in (old) IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the replace function is JavaScript.

Original:

```
var tag_params = {
    prodid: '',
    pagetype: 'cart',
    totalvalue: '%%Amount%%'.replace('$', ''),
};
```

Updated to use `lan`'s method:

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >
    var tag_params = {
        prodid: '',
        pagetype: 'cart',
        totalvalue: '%%Amount%%',
    };

    tag_params.totalValue = tag_params.totalValue.replace('$', ''); 
< /script>
```

Comment: then you need to do what @lan said.

Comment: @osakagreg What's wrong with that? When you try to access `tag_params.totalvalue` later, the value will be `"4.50"`. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @abc123 I just edited your answer because you need to reassign the value of `tag_params.totalValue` after replacing. You might want to include your original solution as well, just to have both visible

Comment: Thank you Ian and @abc123. However, it doesn't appear to be executing correctly, it is just echoing.  Here is the source code when the page executes with the updated code:  

<script type="text/javascript">
var tag_params = {
prodid: '',
pagetype: 'cart',
totalvalue: '$4.50',
};
tag_params.totalvalue = tag_params.totalvalue.replace('$', '');
</script>

Comment: @osakagreg under  tag_params.totalvalue = tag_params.totalvalue.replace('$', ''); add alert(tag_params.totalvalue) it will be without the $....perhaps you need to move the %% to after the value is changed.  You might be able to do it inside the %%Amount.replace('$', '')%% it really depends on how that magic is working.

Answer (score 0):

tag_params.totalValue.replace('$', '');